# How to stop Yclas from stripping PHP tags

Tags: php

I am using a sitebuilder, Yclas to build a website.
Currently, I have designed a form to be submitted using AJAX and PHP. I can not proceed, however, as the sitebuilder keeps 'stripping' my PHP code.

If I input

```
<?php
   echo 'Hello';
?>
```

The result is:

```
<!--?php
   echo 'Hello';
?-->
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put PHP everywhere you can put HTML. Get hosting that supports PHP.